# Fréchet derivative of a smooth $ \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $ mapping lifted to Banach spaces.

Tags: taylor-expansion, inverse-problems, frechet-derivative

I have been trying to make sense of the proof of Lemma 3.1 in the article [Stabilizing inverse problems by internal data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1819.pdf) by P. Kuchment and D. Steinhauer. The lemma is on page 6 and the proof is found on page 17. Most of it makes sense to me, however, what I don't understand is how they obtain equation (60).

They state that they apply Taylor's theorem to $ F $ to obtain the inequality, but I have a few problems in following exactly how they are doing this. Here are my thoughts.

$ F(y,z,w) $ is assumed to be smooth for $ y,z \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ w > 0 $, thus a Taylor explansion is fine:
$$ F(x+\delta x) = F(x) + \nabla F(x)\cdot\delta x + \delta x^T H_{F(\xi(x))}\delta x, $$
where $ x = (y,z,w) $ and $ \delta x = (\delta y, \delta z, \delta w) $. However, I have a problem with the parameter $ |\mathbf{h}_0 + \mathbf{h}| $ in their expression for $ E $. Somehow it seems to me like the expand $ F(f_0+f,g_0+g,|\mathbf{h}_0+\mathbf{h}|) $ using the above Taylor expansion, by putting $ w = |\mathbf{h}_0| $ and $ \delta w = \frac{\mathbf{h}_0\cdot\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h_0}|}, $ which I don't understand how they can do, as $ |\mathbf{h}_0+\mathbf{h}| \neq |\mathbf{h}_0| + \frac{\mathbf{h}_0\cdot\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}_0|} $ in general. And since $ \mathbf{h} $ is an $ L^2(\Omega)^n $-function I feel like there is even more complexity than this simple vector relation to consider.

Can anyone explain what it is I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ \delta w $ satisfy $ |h_0 +h| = |h_0| + \delta w $, then 
$$ \delta w = |h_0 +h | - |h_0| = \frac{|h|^2 + 2(h_0,h)}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|}. $$

Let $ E $ be as in the article,
$$
\begin{aligned}
   E &= F(f_0+f,g_0+g,\underbrace{|h_0+h|}_{|h_0|+\delta w})-F(f_0,g_0,|h_0|) -\nabla F(f_0,g_0,|h_0|)\cdot\left(f,g,\frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the Taylor expansion, $ x = (f_0,g_0,|h_0|) $, $ \delta x = (f,g,\delta w) $,
$$ F(x+\delta x) = F(x) + \nabla F(x)\cdot\delta x + \delta x^T H_{F(\xi)}\delta x, $$
with $ \xi = \xi(\delta x) $, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
   E &= \partial_wF(f_0,g_0,|h_0|)\left(\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right) + (f,g,\delta w)^T H_{F(\xi)}(f,g,\delta w).
\end{aligned}
$$
We have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|} &= \frac{|h|^2}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} + \frac{2(h_0,h)}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|} \\
&=\frac{|h|^2}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} + \left(\frac{h_0}{|h_0|}\left(\frac{|h_0|-|h_0+h|}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|}\right),h\right) \\
&=\frac{|h|^2}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} - \left(\frac{h_0}{|h_0|}\left(\frac{|h|^2+2(h_0,h)}{(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2}\right),h\right) \\
&=\frac{|h|^2}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} - \frac{|h|^2(h_0,h)}{|h_0|(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2} - \frac{2(h_0,h)^2}{|h_0|(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2}. \\
\left|\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right|&\leq \frac{|h|^2}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} + \frac{|h|^3}{(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2} + \frac{2|h_0|\cdot|h|^2}{(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2} \\
&= |h|^2\left(\frac{1}{|h_0+h|+|h_0|} + \frac{|h|+2|h_0|}{(|h_0+h|+|h_0|)^2}\right) \leq C_1|h|^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
The constant comes from $ |h(x)| < m $ on $ \Omega\backslash U $.

We note that since $ D^\alpha F $ is continuous and all of $ f_0,f,g_0,g,|h_0|,|h| $ are bounded on $ \Omega\backslash U $, $ H_{F(\xi)} $ is bounded, i.e. there is a constant $ |H_{F(\xi)}v| \leq C_2|v| $.

Finally we consider $ \delta w^2 $,
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\delta w| &\leq \left|\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right| + \left|\frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right| \leq C_1|h|^2 + |h| \\
|\delta w|^2 & \leq (C_1^2m^2 + 1 + 2C_1m)|h|^2 = C_3|h|^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
With all of this in place, let $ C $ denote an arbitrary positive constant, not necessarily the same every time
$$
\begin{aligned}
|E| &= \left|\partial_wF(f_0,g_0,|h_0|)\left(\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right) + (f,g,\delta w)^T H_{F(\xi)}(f,g,\delta w)\right| \\
&\leq \left|\partial_wF(f_0,g_0,|h_0|)\right|\cdot\left|\delta w - \frac{(h_0,h)}{|h_0|}\right| + \left|(f,g,\delta w)^T H_{F(\xi)}(f,g,\delta w)\right| \\
&\leq \left|\partial_wF(f_0,g_0,|h_0|)\right|C_1|h|^2 + \left|(f,g,\delta w)\right|\cdot\left|H_{F(\xi)}(f,g,\delta w)\right| \\
&\leq C|h|^2 + C_2|(f,g,\delta w)|^2 \leq C|h|^2 + C_2(|f|^2+|g|^2+|\delta w|^2) \\
&\leq C|h|^2 + C_2(|f|^2+|g|^2+C_3|h|^2) \leq C(|f|^2+|g|^2+|h|^2).
\end{aligned}
$$